# How can I create different content slides?

Tags: latex, beamer

I know how to create different backgrounds for title slides with

```
\defbeamertemplate{background}{title_horizontal}{
   ...
}
```

then assign them to the title page (and remove footline for title) with

```
\def\ps@titlepage@horizontal{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background}[title_horizontal]
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
}
```

and then create a text layout with matching background with

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{custom}[1]{
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{horizontal}}
   {
      \thispagestyle{titlepage@horizontal}
   }{}
   ...
}
```

and use them in the document with

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[custom][horizontal]
```

However, I was not able to find anything about how to create and select different layouts of normal content slides.

Is it possible to create different layouts for normal content slides in a similar way?
What is the keyword for content slides?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with different layouts, but maybe https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1162#a1369 could be useful

Comment: With content slides, do you mean the table of contents?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: I mean one type of layout where there is an image on the left hand side and the text only on the right and then a normal slide that has text over the full width of the page.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: With content slides I mean normal slides in a presentation. So not title slides, not section slides, but normal slides that containt the text.

Comment: I wouldn't use a special layout to place image and text side by side - instead just normal columns within the frame.

Comment: This will be difficult if the image is over the whole paperheight and therefore under the normal title. Also this slide should not show a footnote and headnote...

Comment: with footnote and headnote you mean the footline and headline? Use a `plain` frame to hide those. If you need to fill the whole paperheight, I'd use tikz in the `background canvas`, see the answer I linked to earlier.

Comment: The solution with background canvas seems nice. However, how do I define the background specific text area then?

Comment: You can use columns and leave one of them empty to make room for the background

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same technique as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1162#a1369 :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{image}[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east] at (current page.east) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default]%
}
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{myimage}[]{
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[image][#1]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,myimage=example-image-golden-upright]
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
image frame
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
regular
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does help with different backgrounds. Thank you for that. However it does not solve the problem with different layouts. Meaning I also want to specify centrally where the text goes for this type of slide. So the user can simply use this and does not have to be bothered by details.